# tomcat debugging

Tags: debugging, tomcat

I am working on a project where the backend code is in Java.
I want to debug this code and am running tomcat in the debug mode correctly .

I have the Java code in Eclipse where I set up a new debug config for Remote Java Application and start the debugging.It shows no error but it is not breaking at the breakpoint.

So the Tomcat Webapps folder has only a copy of the Servlet classes and my Java code is in a folder at some other place.

Is this the reason that I am not being able to link them properly

Comment: When you start debug in eclipse, do you switch to debug mode and see the task running? Is your code in tomcat up-to-date from your java code?

Comment: yepp..i can see Server VM running in debug mode..i think i am putting breakpoint in wrong place.how do i get the origin place where the server starts?Is it the HTTPServlet class.

Comment: why did someone vote a -1 for this question?

Comment: because it is off topic, this is more for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), stackoverflow expects questions specific for implementatation issues, try the FAQ (I did not downvote)

Answer (score 1):

You have to start tomcat with the JPDA options in order to debug remotely.  Under *nix, issue "catalina jpda start" instead of "catalina start".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a remote debug to figure out a problem in code, then your code locally must be the same.  Also remember to connect to the correct port, 8000, I believe.